# Normalizing symmetric wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, normalization, identical-particles

Wikipedia and other sources say that the normalized symmetric ket for $N$ particles with quantum numbers $n_1, n_2, ...,n_N$ is
$$|n_1n_2...n_N;S\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{\Pi_km_k!}{N!}}\sum_P|n_{P(1)}\rangle|n_{P(2)}\rangle...|n_{P(N)}\rangle$$
Where $m_k$ is the number of particles in stake $k$. My question is, since for every $m$ particles in a same state there are $m!$ permutations of the base kets, shouldn't the $m_k!$ be in the denominator to account for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the idea will be clear by a simple example. First consider $|123 \rangle$. The symmetrized version of this is proportional to 
$$|123\rangle + |132\rangle + |231\rangle + |213\rangle + |312\rangle + |321\rangle $$
with $6 = 3!$ entries in total. So we need to multiply by $1/\sqrt{3!}$ to normalize this state properly, in accordance with the formula. Now consider $|112 \rangle$. The symmetrized version is proportional to 
$$|112 \rangle + |121 \rangle + |211 \rangle.$$
Now there are only $3 = 3!/2!$ entries, so we need to multiply by $\sqrt{2!}/\sqrt{3!}$, again in agreement with the formula. In a more extreme case, consider $|111 \rangle$. The symmetrized version is just $|111 \rangle$, so the normalization constant is $1 = \sqrt{3!}/\sqrt{3!}$, also in agreement with the formula.

If you want a description in terms of words, what's going on is that our description should treat the particles symmetrically because they're identical. So if you have a state like $|123 \rangle$, you need to split it between $N!$ symmetric possibilities. That's what the $1/\sqrt{N!}$ factor account for. But if you have a situation where some of the particles are in the same state on the left-hand side, then those particles are *already* treated symmetrically. So there are fewer than $N!$ states on the right-hand side, which is why the $\prod_k m_k!$ appears in the numerator rather than the denominator.

Comment: Right. I was under the impression that the permutations included exchanging particles in the same state. Thank you!

Comment: @PhineasNicolson Probably this response is too late as of now, but you were right in saying that the $m_k!$ coefficient could come in the denominator IF, as you said, "the permutations included exchanging particles in the same state." The textbook on Statistical Mechanics by Greiner that I'm using does precisely what you were expecting.